# SymPy rounding behaviour

Tags: python, sympy

I was investigating different rounding method using Python built-in solution and some other external libraries such SymPy and while doing so I stumbled upon some cases that I need help with understanding the reason behind it.

Ex-1:

```
print(round(1.0065,3))
```

output:
1.006

In the first case, using the Python built-in rounding function the output was 1.006 instead of 1.007 and I can understand that this is not a mistake as Python rounds to the nearest even and that's known as Bankers rounding.

And this is why I from the beginning started searching for another way to control the rounding behaviour. With a quick search, I've found decimal.Decimal module which can easily handle decimal values and efficiently round is using quantize() as in this example:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext, ROUND_HALF_UP
context= getcontext()
context.rounding='ROUND_HALF_UP'

print(Decimal('1.0065').quantize(Decimal('.001')))
```

output:1.007

This is a very good solution but the only problem is it is not easy to be hardcoded in long math expressions as I'll need to convert every number to string then after using decimal I will pass it the precession as in the form of "0.001" instead of writing '3' directly as in the case of built-in round.

While searching for another solution I found that SymPy, which I already use a lot in my scripts, offers some very powerful functions that might help but when I tried it the output was not as I expected.

Ex-1 using SymPy sympify():

```
print(sympify(1.0065).evalf(3))
```

output: 1.01

Ex-2 using SymPy N (normalize):

```
print(N(1.0065,3))
```

output: 1.01

Af first the output was a little bit weird but after investigating I realized that N and sympify already performing round right but rounding to significant figures, not to decimal places.

And here the questions come:

As I can use with Decimal objects getcontext().rounding='ROUND_HALF_UP' to change the rounding behaviour, is there a way to change the N and sympify rounding behaviour to decimal places instead of significant figures?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-implementing decimal rounding in SymPy, perhaps use `decimal` to do the rounding, but hide the calculation in a utility function:

```
import sympy as sym
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal as D

def dround(d, ndigits, rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP):
    result = D(str(d)).quantize(D('0.1')**ndigits, rounding=rounding)
    # result = sym.sympify(result)  # if you want a SymPy Float
    return result

for x in [0.0065, 1.0065, 10.0065, 100.0065]:
    print(dround(x, 3))
```

prints

```
0.007
1.007
10.007
100.007
```

Answer (score 1):

The n of `evalf` gives the first n significant digits of x (measured from the left). If you use x.round(3) it will round x to the nth digit from the decimal point and can be positive (right of decimal pt) or negative (left of decimal pt).

```
>>> for x in '0.0065, 1.0065, 10.0065, 100.0065'.split(', '):
...     print S(x).round(3)
0.006
1.006
10.007
100.007

>>> int(S(12345).round(-2))
12300
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `N` and `evalf` are essentially the same thing; `N(x, n)` amounts to  `sympify(x).evalf(n)`. In your case, since x is a Python float, it's easier to use `N` because it sympifies the input.

To get three digits after decimal dot, use `N(x, 3 + log(x, 10) + 1)`. The adjustment `log(x, 10) + 1` is 0 when x is between 0.1 and 1; in this case the number of significant digits is the same as the number of digits after the decimal dot. If x is larger, we get more significant digits.

Example:

```
for x in [0.0065, 1.0065, 10.0065, 100.0065]:
    print(N(x, 3 + log(x, 10) + 1))
```

prints

```
0.006
1.007
10.007
100.007
```

The transition from 6 to 7 is curious, but not entirely surprising. These numbers are not exactly represented in binary system, so the truncation to nearest double-precision float may be a factor here. I've made a few additional observation on this effect [on my blog](https://calculus7.org/2016/09/07/bankers-rounding-and-floating-point-arithmetics/).